# Java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in EclipseLink Project

Tags: exception, eclipselink

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRdxm.png)i have a problem with setting up my Eclipse Link Project. I already imported the EclipseLink library and as well i imported the jdbc-driver, but if i try to run this project as a java application suddenly this error appears.
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

imported libraries
converted to jpa-project

Comment: More information would help. At a minimum, what is the error message and the stack trace from the error? Turn on logging for your libraries and see if anything else might hint at what is going wrong.

Comment: I linked an image to my question. I hope it is useful !

Comment: Does this one not show you a "Caused by" somewhere in the stack? You have to follow it through to figure out what is causing it specifically. O